# Using default column with group by statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to use Default value column in GROUP BY.
The default column is created in Select statement.

I have tried to use the default column value `'A'` in group by(I know i cannot use the alias value).

This is what I have tried.

```
Select Name, 'A' as 'ID',SUM(Amount) FROM Customer
GROUP BY Name, 'A'
```

I am getting the following error message:

> Msg 164, Level 15, State 1, Line 18
>   Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an >outer reference.

Comment: As 'A' is a constant, you don't need to add it to the group by list. And having single quotes around 'ID' might be causing issues too. Get rid of them or use [ID].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grouping by that additional column will not do any difference and will be the same as:

```
Select Name, 'A' as 'ID',SUM(Amount) FROM Customer
GROUP BY Name
```

Comment: Well, technically adding `'A'` to the `GROUP BY` *does* make a difference because it results in an error.  However, if it worked, it wouldn't logically affect the results.